# What is this drive in my computer?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, malware, system-restore

I was trying to create a system restore point in my Windows 10 laptop.

I noticed one of the drives had a weird name, like this ?\Volume{f2f20ba-117 . . .

What is this drive? Is it potentially something harmful?

If this is not the right place to ask, I would appreciate it if you could let me know where I can ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you saw is the GUID of one of your disk partitions, they are how Windows identifies your storage volumes. It is hardly harmful, and without a storage device your computer simply won't boot into a Operating System.

GUID stands for [Globally Unique IDentifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), simply put it identifies a storage volume, like ID numbers for storage volumes.

Now to demonstrate this better, I will use some examples:

```powershell
Get-Volume | Select DriveLetter, FriendlyName, FileSystemType, Size, SizeRemaining, ObjectId, UniqueId | Format-List

PS C:\Windows\System32> get-volume | Select DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel, FileSystemType, Size, SizeRemaining, ObjectId, UniqueId | Format-List

DriveLetter     : D
FileSystemLabel : Windows
FileSystemType  : NTFS
Size            : 499563884544
SizeRemaining   : 51168251904
ObjectId        : {1}\\DESKTOP-8HME1JD\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{fdf7c64a-4d23-11eb-8882-806e6f6e6963}:VO:\\?\Volume{53fb3313-0000-0000-0000-040000000000}\"
UniqueId        : \\?\Volume{53fb3313-0000-0000-0000-040000000000}\

DriveLetter     : C
FileSystemLabel :
FileSystemType  : NTFS
Size            : 2000396742656
SizeRemaining   : 1779709784064
ObjectId        : {1}\\DESKTOP-8HME1JD\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{fdf7c64a-4d23-11eb-8882-806e6f6e6963}:VO:\\?\Volume{b90020bf-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\"
UniqueId        : \\?\Volume{b90020bf-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\

DriveLetter     : E
FileSystemLabel : Windows OS
FileSystemType  : NTFS
Size            : 1000204398592
SizeRemaining   : 1000066396160
ObjectId        : {1}\\DESKTOP-8HME1JD\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{fdf7c64a-4d23-11eb-8882-806e6f6e6963}:VO:\\?\Volume{c817c634-0000-0000-0000-040000000000}\"
UniqueId        : \\?\Volume{c817c634-0000-0000-0000-040000000000}\

DriveLetter     : F
FileSystemLabel : WinPE
FileSystemType  : FAT32
Size            : 15469191168
SizeRemaining   : 15469166592
ObjectId        : {1}\\DESKTOP-8HME1JD\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{fdf7c64a-4d23-11eb-8882-806e6f6e6963}:VO:\\?\Volume{fdf7c663-4d23-11eb-8882-806e6f6e6963}\"
UniqueId        : \\?\Volume{fdf7c663-4d23-11eb-8882-806e6f6e6963}\
```

As you see, every drives has a different UniqueId.

Comment: Thank you so much! I do think it is the GUID. Just one question, why is only that drive identified by GUID? In my page, the other 2 drives are called "Windows C: (System)" and "Recovery (D:)", but only this drive has the GUID name with "\\?\volume . . .. ".

Comment: It might be the EFI partition, as it doesn't have a drive letter, but that's just a guess, as your question doesn't provide sufficient information to help determine its nature, I need the report of `diskpart`, `devmgmt.msc`, `diskmgmt.msc` and the PowerShell command `Get-Volume | Select DriveLetter, FriendlyName, FileSystemType, Size, SizeRemaining, ObjectId, UniqueId | Format-List` to identify its nature. You need to run elevated PowerShell for the command, if you don't know how, Google it.